# Theory of Numbers Properties of GCD (Greatest Common Divisor)

Tags: number-theory

I am a student in Undergraduate Mathematics, and I'm struggling to number theory ... I have this problem gcd, and do not know how to do it, and still do not study, congruences, Diophantine equations or, among other matters more advanced ... I'm used to divisibility, and some properties and/or theorems gcd ... Help me, please ...

question
a) Show that if

$(a, b) = 1$, $\Longrightarrow$ $(a · c, b) = (c, b)$.

Comment: Note: Do not speak, nor write, english, use a translator, then I urge you to write without abbreviations. Thank you.

Comment: I tried to get ...
But not out ...
Did ...


Demo:
$(a⋅c,b)=j$ e $(c,b)=k$ $\Longrightarrow$ $j=k$

Comment: Have you already in your course the theorem that if $x$ divides $mn$, and $\gcd(x,n)=1$, then $x$ divides $m$?

Comment: Is it obvious to you that $(c,b)|(ac,b)$?

Comment: not André Nicolas

Comment: Yes Thomas $(c,b)=d$;  $d|c$; e $d|b$;

a

$d|c$ $\longrightarrow$ $d|a⋅c$ $\longrightarrow$


$(c,b)|(a⋅c,b)$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** It is sufficient to show:
$$d\mid c \wedge d\mid b \Leftrightarrow d\mid ac \wedge d\mid b$$
for any $d\in\mathbb Z$ (*why?*)

**Hint 2:** For the "$\Leftarrow$"-implication, use that $d\mid ac$ and $d\mid bc$, so $d$ divides their gcd.

Answer (score 0):

We use the following theorem from Number Theory.

$$
g=(a,b) \Longleftrightarrow ax+by=g
$$ for some
integers $x$ and $y$. **

Now consider $(a,b)=1$ then you can write
$$
ax+by=1\quad  (1)
$$
Let $g=(a\cdot c,b)$ then 
invoking the above theorem again 
$$
ac(x_{1})+b(y_{1})=g\quad (2)
$$
for some integers $x_{1}$ and $y_{1}$.

Now if we show the following
$$
c(ax_{2})+b(y_{2})=g
$$
we are done. To do that, look the hint below.

**Hint** Consider the two equations above.
Multiply equation $1$ by g and so some algebra.

Comment: I assume that "NT" is an abbreviation for "Number Theory"

Comment: yes edited to reflect your comment.

Comment: The above theorem is known as _Bezout's lemma_. It's proof involves the concept of the _Euclidean division/algorithm_. This might be trivial, but exceeds divisibility properties, which were required by the OP.